# Hibernate inheritance: join query with criteria

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have an entity `AA` that has a many to many relationships with an entity `BB` and `BB` extend another entity `CC` ( with inheritance strategy JOIN).

```
    @Entity
    class AA {

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "AA_BB", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_AA", referencedColumnName = "ID_AA"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_BB", referencedColumnName = "ID_BB"), uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "ID_AA", "ID_BB" }))
    private List<BB> bb = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Entity
    class BB extends CC {
    }

    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = JOINED)
    abstract class CC {

    @Column
    private long code;

    }
```

I am trying to create a query with criteria to retrieve all the `AA` that has a list of `BB` that contains a code equal to 100.

The following code doesn't work and I am getting an exception of type:
**nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists**

```
            criteria.createAlias("bb", "b", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("b.code", 100));
```

Comment: Is this all the criteria? For master master-datail I'm missing reference to master here. I would fetch master - AA then join BB with fetchJoin to have all of them. After that I would put filter to have b.code = 100.

Comment: @MichałZaborowski this not all the criteria it remains this part `Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(AA.class);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to comment - you need create criteria for both master (AA), and detail (BB).
Here is something that should work:

```
Criteria aaCriteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(AA.class,"a");
Criteria bbCriteria = aaCriteria.createCriteria("bb","b");
bbCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("b.code", 100));
```

Having criteria object for both levels you can add restrictions for both of them.